# DB2 SQL - Convert Decimal CC + YYMMDD to Date

Tags: sql, db2

I have two packed decimal fields, a CC and then YYMMDD. When you add them together you get this:

```
CC    YYMMDD -> Together They Create a 'Date'
20    170829    20170829
19    980123    19980123
```

I want both of these together, and to create a `USO` date: `2017-08-29`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick. Use the `TRIM()` if you need to, in case your `CC` value is a four digit packed column.

```sql
SELECT 
   DATE(INSERT(INSERT(LEFT(CHAR(TRIM(CHAR(cc)) || CHAR(yymmdd),8),5,0,'-'),8,0,'-'))
     FROM yourTable
```

Results will be `YYYY-MM-DD` as a `Date`.